# passing arguments to the bind() function

Tags: c, sockets

i have this programm which should only bind a socket to a port and i always get

> failure while binding.

I can compile it without a problem.

should i add something to the `servAddr`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "Practical.h"

int main(int argc , char* argv[]){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Parameters : <server Port>");
    }

    in_port_t servPort=atoi(argv[1]);

    int servSock;
    if(servSock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)<0){
        printf("error socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port=htons(servPort);

    if(bind(servSock,(struct sockaddr*) &servAddr,sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){
        printf("failure while binding");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `errno` ?

Comment: Instead of printing generic error messages, it would be worth your while to use `perror()` to emit messages specific to the problem.

Comment: Why don't you replace `printf()` with `perror()` and see what the reason for the failure is?

Comment: In the error cases, change `printf` to `perror` so it tells you *why* they failed.

Comment: Another nice example where Yoda-conditions would have saved you (and us) time.

Comment: `gcc -Wall` displays warning `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value` for this code. clang version 3.5.0 doesn't even require any options to enable similar warning.

Answer (score 6):

`=` has priority lower than `<`, add extra braces:

```
if((servSock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))<0){
  printf("error socket");}
```

Without these braces `servSock` is `1` or `0`, that is definitely not what you want. Also note that without priviledges you can not bind to ports lower that 1024.